# More efficient way to write this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three relations (simplified for the problem)

```
SUPPLIER(SNO)
PART(PNO, PNAME)
SHIPMENT(SNO, PNO)
```

where `SNO` and `PNO` are foreign keys matching the primary keys of `SUPPLIER` and `PART`

I wrote a query to find `SNO` of all Suppliers that ship to P2 and P4. The query works but it seems inefficient. I excluded all `PNO` that were not P2 or P4

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.SNO, PNO
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN SHIPMENT ON SUPPLIER.SNO = SHIPMENT.SNO
WHERE PNO <> 'P1' AND PNO <> 'P3' AND PNO <> 'P5' AND PNO <> 'P6'
```

There has to be as better way to write this query. I am using mssql-server

EDIT: I am just learning sql and was not aware of the IN operator. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why exclude the other `pno`s and not just include `p2` and `p4`?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data.  Also explain why you don't just use `PN0 IN ('P2', 'P4')`.

Comment: @Mureinik I am just learning sql and was not aware of the IN operator

Comment: efficiency-wise - `IN` isn't very efficient, you're likely better off using `WHERE` even though it's more verbose.  Also if you are using Management studio, you have the ability to display the "Estimated Execution Plan" (Ctrl-L) to see where your query is taking the most time and also you can Analyze the Query in the tuning advisor to optimize indexing and such

Comment: @kemotoe: The question is mainly: Is there a reason that you exclude records rather than saying which ones you want? This would be `WHERE PN0 = 'P2' OR PN0 = 'P4'` or shorter `PN0 IN ('P2', 'P4')`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I didn't use `OR` because I needed the Suppliers that shipped to both. I was unaware of the `IN` operator, which solved my problem.

Comment: No, IN does the same as OR. And if you don't only look for suppliers shipping to P2 and/or P4, but only those that ship to both P2 and P4, the query will have to look very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the task is to find records with PNO either 'P2' or 'P4', you should select these and not look into the table, see that there are only values from 'P1' to 'P6', and exclude these. Once someone adds a 'P7' record, your query will fail, because it won't only get records for 'P2' and 'P4', but also for 'P7'.

An appropriate WHERE clause would be

```
WHERE PNO = 'P2' OR PNO = 'P4'
```

or as has been shown

```
WHERE PNO IN ('P2','P4')
```

When dealing with data from more than one table, you should always qualify the columns, i.e. use `SHIPMENT.PNO` instead of merely `PNO`.

It is a good idea to use table aliases then, to get your query shorter. And for readability you shouldn't write evertything in caps.

```
SELECT supp.sno, ship.pno
FROM supplier supp
JOIN shipment ship ON supp.sno = ship.sno
WHERE ship.pno IN ('P1','P4');
```

And one more thing: As the shipping table holds all the values your results shall show, you don't need the supplier table in your query of course.

```
SELECT sno, pno
FROM shipment
WHERE pno IN ('P1','P4');
```

If your table contains duplicates, you may want to select distinct rows with `SELECT DISTINCT sno, pno` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could  use a not in

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.SNO, PNO
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN SHIPMENT ON SUPPLIER.SNO = SHIPMENT.SNO
WHERE PNO not in ('P1' , 'P3' ,'P5' , 'P6')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
 You can use below query to make it efficient,

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.SNO, PNO
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN SHIPMENT ON SUPPLIER.SNO = SHIPMENT.SNO
WHERE PNO not in ('P1', 'P3', 'P5', 'P6');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use not in.

```
Where PNO not in ('P1', 'P3', 'P5', 'P6')
```

Or maybe even simple would be

```
where PNO in ('P2', 'P4')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the IN clause

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.SNO, PNO
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN SHIPMENT ON SUPPLIER.SNO = SHIPMENT.SNO
WHERE PNO IN ('P2','P4')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.SNO, PNO
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN SHIPMENT ON SUPPLIER.SNO = SHIPMENT.SNO
WHERE PNO IN ('P2','P4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
SELECT SUPPLIER.SNO, PNO
FROM SUPPLIER
JOIN SHIPMENT ON SUPPLIER.SNO = SHIPMENT.SNO
WHERE PNO  in 'P2, P4'
```

Comment: You got the in clause wrong. See the other answers.

Comment: missing some parentheses Polina